# How to refresh Grid GWT after getting data from database_Now it keeps the Gird in the First call

Tags: gwt, grid, refresh, gxt

I am new with GWT_GXT

I use MVP(model-view-Presenter)

In Presenter, i call RPC to get data From database. After that i get a List data -> I set it for view

In view, code is below

```
@Override
public void setDeleteAllTest(List<DeleteAllTestModel> deleteAllTests) {
   final ListStore<DeleteAllTestModel> listStore = new ListStore<DeleteAllTestModel>();
    listStore.add(deleteAllTests);
    gridView = new PMTGridDeleteAllTest<DeleteAllTestModel>().getPMTGridDeleteAllTest(listStore);
    gridView.setAutoWidth(true);

}
```

@Override
    protected void onRender(Element parent, int pos) {
        super.onRender(parent, pos);

```
    ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
    cp.setBodyBorder(false);
    cp.setHeading("");
    cp.setButtonAlign(Style.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER.CENTER);
    cp.setLayout(new FitLayout());
    cp.setSize(1200, 400);
    cp.add(gridView);

    verticalPanel.add(cp);

    verticalPanel.add(nameField);

    verticalPanel.add(cancelButton);

    add(verticalPanel);
    cancelButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent buttonEvent) {
            PolicyDeleteAllTestDialog.this.hide();
        }
    });

    getButtonById("ok").hide();
}
```

The Problem is that Gird is not refresh and update new data_ It only displays (the first Grid in the first Call) .. It always keep the first View( I use dialog to show grid)..

Help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly remember how it works and it really is what you need. But there is something like `gridView.refresh();`. I remember I sometime used to use `grid.getView().refresh(true);` but it's been a while. Also I think there is a concept named `ListLoader` that might be useful. I am not sure of myself but if I were you I would have a look at `listLoader`. I hope this will help you one way or another, sorry if it does not.

Comment: Still if I understand your problem this might help you: http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1.0-beta/ui/grid/GridLoadingRpc.html